# UPDATE record in one database with values from another in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to update my new database with data from 1 column in my old database.  Basically based on matching ItemID's I need to set the Description column in my new DB with the values in the old DB.  I can see what needs to be updated when I do a join but I am not sure how to handle this update properly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE t1
SET    Description = t2.Description
FROM   db1.dbo.foo t1
       JOIN db2.dbo.foo t2
         ON t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID

SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.foo
--prevents changes from being committed
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: @Slee - Yep. You might want to put it inside an explicit transaction and do a quick review of the results before commiting as well.

Comment: hello @MartinSmith could you please add the the explicit transaction to the example above pls?? I never worked before with transaction and I would like to start for this kind of things.

Comment: Don't forget to add the server first (like I did) using sp_addlinkedserver