# Updating columns values from another table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I want to update my table from another table in another database.I have two table that has two same columns.There are ID and iexp column.What i want is update every row from k_monster table to my database's k_monster table but there are other columns such as iHP iMP so i want to just update iExp column.what do you suggest?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE record in one database with values from another in SQL Server 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735123/update-record-in-one-database-with-values-from-another-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Target_Database` is the database where the table is that you want to update and `Source_Database` is the database where the table is you are using to update from.

Your query should look something like this.....

```
USE [Target_Database]
GO

UPDATE t
 SET t.iexp  = S.iexp 
FROM K_monster t 
INNER JOIN [Source_Database].[Schema].[K_monster] S 
ON t.ID = S.ID
GO
```

Comment: thank you bro!solved 
USE [KN_Online]
GO

UPDATE t
 SET t.iExp  = S.iExp 
FROM K_Monster t 
INNER JOIN [newmyko].[dbo].[K_Monster] S 
ON t.ssid = S.ssid
GO

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link similar to this type of question:

Additionally I would suggest you to search before you ask any questions.

[UPDATE record in one database with values from another in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735123/update-record-in-one-database-with-values-from-another-in-sql-server-2008)

This link has similar answer to your question.

More links:

[Update database table from one SQL Server database table to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413855/update-database-table-from-one-sql-server-database-table-to-another)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/how-to-update-one-database-from-another

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58371/sql-update-column-with-data-from-another-table

With Regards

Comment: You should write a quick review when you are posting links in case that some of useful content from those links could be deleted in future.

Comment: @TMNT - As the other user said, please post some useful content from the links. Your answer will become useless once the links are deleted.