# How to Update A database column with B database column?

Tags: sql-server, database

Database A has table named table1 and database B has table named table2. Both table have same structure. I need to update B Database table table2 with data from A database table table1 with rows having column5 = true

So far I have tried this but its not working

```
UPDATE B.dbo.table2
SET table2Id = A_table1.table2Id
FROM A.dbo.table1 as A_table1
WHERE A_table1.Archive = 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating columns values from another table SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760438/updating-columns-values-from-another-table-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do rows from Table A relate to Table B? Assuming there is some natural key that links them together try:

```
UPDATE B
SET table2Id = A_table1.table2Id
FROM A.dbo.table1 as A_table1
inner join B.dbo.table2 as B on A_table1.NaturalKey = B.NaturalKey
WHERE A_table1.Archive = 1
```

Obviously, NaturalKey is whatever column relates the two tables together.